# Scifi anthology containing stories about fighting glass aliens and a boy who becomes a vampire

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration

I assume you guys get thousands of these. Well here goes. 'Several' stories in 1 book, read in the early 80's, dating at least as far back as the 70's and 60's maybe.

Story one is some kind of planetary exploration team. One group comes back into camp bleeding to death and missing fingers. On the wind is some kind of whistling noise, than all these armadillo sized diamond/glass creatures come over the horizon and attack, very fast and sharp little buggers, crew fights back melting some of them with some kind of laser guns, not sure how it ends.

Story two is some other planet, a 'rite of passage' I think where some kid drinks the blood of some creature that has its neck punctured at a ceremony. Basically it turns him into a vampire...

And a couple other stories in the book, mainly after the first story.

Comment: *"armadillo sized"* that seems very specific. Was that mentioned in the book?

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned offhand in [a deleted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/231127/23243), one of the stories at [70s Young Adult science fiction short story collection available in schools](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46629/70s-young-adult-science-fiction-short-story-collection-available-in-schools) fits your description as per [this site's summary](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2013/07/more-science-fiction-tales-roger-elwood.html).

> **The Music of Minox** (Howard Goldsmith) finds an interplanetary mining camp attacked by aliens monsters resembling crystalline porcupines that emit harp-like sounds.
> [image: Title page for "The Music of Minox"]
> [image: Two page spread showing the astronauts fleeing the monsters]

This was only published in [*More Science Fiction Tales: Crystal Creatures, Bird-Things & Other Weirdies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?22831) as far as I can tell, which does feature a story of a boy and a ritual regarding becoming a vampire.

> **A Thirst For Blood** (Arthur Tofte), a story of vampires and interplanetary adventure set in the year 2040, opens with a boy being forced to carry out the grim ritual of decapitating the corpse of his father to cancel a vampiric curse.

However, according to [the copy of the book I found on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/morescienceficti00elwo/page/80/mode/2up), while he opens the story by digging up his vampiric father's corpse and properly disposing of it, the Romany ritual was intended to cure him of being a vampire.

> And in actuality, the murders were due to alien natives with a blood deficiency, the "ritual" involves giving him a native drug that makes him think he's a vampire, and both he and his father suffer from [porphyria](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/porphyria/symptoms-causes/syc-20356066).